# How can I pick the last few digits in a number set?

Tags: javascript, html

Please advise how can I take last two or one digits in a number.

Eg : 
12/5/17
158/63/0

In above numbers just I want to pick 17 in first Eg and 0 in my second Eg.

Suresh

Comment: [Click here before you post your next question.](http://s.tk/onhold)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript's `split()`.

```
var number = "12/5/17".split("/");    // Will return an array: ["12","5","17"]
number[number.length-1];    // Will return the last number in the set
```

Using `[number-1]` is necessary because the array is 0-based.

Hope this helps.
-CE